# Trouble running Tensorflow-gpu GPT-2 model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run OpenAI's GPT-2 model using the Tensorflow GPU running on my NVidia SLI GTX-780 though I keep getting errors regardless of what versions I run or what I do.

```
File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Installed TF:

- tensorboard 1.14.0
- tensorflow 1.14.0
- tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0
- tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1

Python -v 3.6.6

Installed NVIDIA libraries and updated %PATH:

- Cuda toolkit 10.0
- Cudnn64_7

When I have the 9.0 toolkit I get a GPU error: `TensorFlow: Dst tensor is not initialized` so I update to the new tensorflow GPU and then I get the "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." error without understanding what I need to do to fix it.

I've been pulling my hair out for a day trying to get this to work, it works on my Laptop just not my PC.